# How to setPadding to view using animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I try `ValueAnimator` but I can't set multiple properties to it.

```
ValueAnimator animate = ValueAnimator.ofInt(leftO, left, topO, top, rightO, right, bottomO, bottom);
    animate.setDuration(250);
    animate.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            greenTarget.setPadding(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(), ? ? ?);
        }
    });
    animate.start();
```

So, how to do it? Maybe using `ObjectAnimator` instead? If so, how to setPadding there?

Answer (score 1):

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getPaddingRight(), _20dp);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator){
    view.setPadding(_6dp, _6dp, (Integer) 
    valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(), 0);
  }
});
animator.setDuration(200);
animator.start();
```

Comment: I need to update 4 paddings at once. Here you're updating only one.

Comment: If you mean to do it in listener, you're wrong. Because there we can use only calculated value, such as `getAnimatedValue()`. We can't use final values such as left,top etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html) who allow animation between start attributes values (values defined in the xml for example) and changed values ( defined programatically for example).

You need the root layout of your xml, i named it here mViewGroup and the layout type of the direct parent of the view to animate, for example a LinearLayout :

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mViewGroup, new ChangeBound());

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) greenTarget.getLayoutParams();
params.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
greenTarget.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helps.